# OpenTelemetry with InfluxDB and without Collectors

Tags: java, spring-boot, influxdb, open-telemetry

I am new with OpenTelemetry.

I have a Springboot App where I added opentelemetry boot-starter dependency:

```
        <dependency>
            <groupId>io.opentelemetry.instrumentation</groupId>
            <artifactId>opentelemetry-spring-boot-starter</artifactId>
            <version>1.31.0-alpha</version>
        </dependency>
```

I want to send metrics directly to `InfluxDB` but I don't want to Install and Deploy `Collector`

There is not InfluxDb exporter that I could found.

What are my options?

Comment: Does that help? https://github.com/influxdata/telegraf/blob/release-1.28/plugins/outputs/opentelemetry/README.md